# How to show only non empty string values from an array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to iterate through a JSON array in my view, but I want to only show the keys that has values that are non empty strings.

```
design:
{name: "ux", value: "3", $$hashKey: "object:5198"}
{name: "graphic", value: "", $$hashKey: "object:5199"}
{name: "concept", value: "4", $$hashKey: "object:5200"}
{name: "photoshop", value: "", $$hashKey: "object:5201"}
{name: "illustrator", value: "5", $$hashKey: "object:5202"}
{name: "inDesign", value: ""}
{name: "afterEffects", value: ""}
{name: "premierePro", value: "1"}
```

How would I only get the keys of the array while iterating through the array and only show the ones that have a real value.

The current code that I have is:

```
<div class="six columns">
                        <div ng-repeat="skill in employeeDetails.design | limitTo:5:0 | filter:{value:'! '}">
                            {{ skill.name | capitalize }} {{ skill.value }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Just use | filter:{value:'!! '}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` in this case:

```
<div class="six columns">
     <div ng-repeat="skill in employeeDetails.design | limitTo:5:0" ng-if="skill.value !== '' ">
             {{ skill.name | capitalize }} {{ skill.value }}
      </div>
</div>
```

or change your `filter`

```
<div class="six columns">
         <div ng-repeat="skill in employeeDetails.design | limitTo:5:0 | filter:{value:'!! '}" ng-if="skill.value !== '' ">
                 {{ skill.name | capitalize }} {{ skill.value }}
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! I was over thinking it by creating a filter in the module.

Comment: Please accept the answer as it will be useful for other visitors.

Comment: Will do, it has a time limit tho :)

Comment: sure thanks. Let know if you have any other difficulties

Comment: Duplicates are not meant to be answered.

Comment: You marked it duplicate after i gave the answer.